Google Drive API upload to specific folder
I'm trying to create a project that contains nextjs (typescript), nextauth and Google Drive API. Its basic features would be upload, delete and manage folders. I got to the point that I am able to upload files to me Google Drive.
This is the API routes-
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google" 

export const authOptions = ({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "" ,
            clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            authorization: { 
              params: 
              { 
                scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" 
                //
              } 
            },
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({token, user , account} : any){ 
        //console.log("Account Access Token : " , token.accessToken)
        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        }
        return token
      },
      async session({ session, token } : any) {
        const newSession = {
          ...session,
          accessToken: token.accessToken,
        };
      
        //console.log("New Session Object:", newSession);
        return newSession;
      },
    }
})
 

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}

and as for the main component or main function that im using for now
const handleFileUpload = async (e : any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const metadata = {
      name:file.name
    }
    const body = new FormData()
    body.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)],{
      type: "application/json"
    }))
      body.append("file" , file)
 
      console.log("Body Data : ", body) 
      try { 
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart` ,
          { 
            method : "POST",
            body : body,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`
            }
        })

        console.log("Response : " , response)

        if(response.ok){
          const responseData = await response.json()
          const fileId = responseData.id
          const fileUrl = `http"//drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view`  
        } 
      } catch (error){
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);  
      }
  } 

Now what I'm having a issue with is the uploading to a specific folder
even after verifying my accessToken to make sure its working properly and using 'parents={folderId} its still not following the upload location, though it still upload but only on the default location (My Drive), I just can't understand it properly. I would appreciate if anyone can explain to me and help me understand here.
The code is from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abyoZC6dLCc

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to upload a file to the specific folder using Drive API.

In this case, please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the metadata of your request body is modified.
From:
const metadata = {
  name:file.name
}

To:
const metadata = {
  name: file.name,
  parents: ["###"] // Please set the folder ID.
}

Note:

From your showing script, I thought that you might use the service account. If my understanding is correct, if you want to upload the file to the folder on the service account's drive or the service account has already had permission to write the folder, it can be simply done by the above modification. But, if you want to upload the file to a different drive from the service account's drive and the service account has never had permission to write, please share the folder with the service account and upload the file to the folder. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Method: files.create


thanks, that helped alot, now i can try finding out is the GET, Thanks alot much appreciated

@user14670265 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
